# What is the definiton of repertoire shift in B cells?

Tags: immune-system, memory

I am new to biology and trying to understand this term.

Couldn't find a comprehensive defintion.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the [Tour] and the [Help on asking good questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) where you will read that you are required to show the research you have done before posting. In biology we deal more in explanations and usage than formal definitions, and if you search for "B cell repertoire shift" you will find many papers on this topic. Read their introductions and if you still can't understand post a sentence or two and explain what it is specifically that is causing problems.